# Globalize3 - two translations in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, globalize3

I use gem globalize3.

I want to get a translation posts in two languages​​, first in English and then in Russian in one index view. And I want to post that is not in English, was located below in Russian after the English posts.
My problem is that since I have a default locale :en, and if:

```
@posts = Post.with_translations(:en)
```

I get posts in english as I need, if:

```
@posts_ru = Post.with_translations(:ru)
```

I get posts in english too..Probably because the default locale English

How I can get @posts  in english and then in russian together in one index view?
please help me!
thanks in advance!

Comment: two queries but clear code: `@posts_en = Post.translations.where(:locale => "en"); @posts_ru = Post.translations.where(:locale => "ru")`. Otherwise, group queries and sort.

Answer (score 6):

You can get all translations like this:

```
@posts = Post.with_translations
```

And in your view use it like below:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

  <%= post.name(:en) %>
  <%= post.name(:ru) %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: in this case, if the post does not have an English translation, but only Russian, it will not appear below

Comment: <%= post.name(:en) if post.name(:en).present? %>